# Java: Caching of non-volatile variables by different threads

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile

The situation is the following:

1. I have an object with lots of setters and getters.
2. Instance of this object is created in a one particular thread where all values are set. Initially I create an "empty" object using new statement and only then I call some setters methods based on some complicated legacy logic.
3. Only then this object became available to all other threads that use only getters.

**The question:** Do I have to make all variables of this class volatile or not?

Concerns:

- Creation of a new instance of the object and setting all its values
  is separated in time.
- But all other threads have no idea about this
  new instance until all values are set. So other threads shall not
  have a cache of not fully initialized object. Isn't it?

*Note:* I am aware about builder pattern, but I cannot apply it there for several other reasons :(

**EDITED:**
As I feel two answers from Mathias and axtavt do not match very well, I would like to add an example:

Let's say we have a `foo` class:

```
class Foo {   
    public int x=0;   
}
```

and two threads are using it as described above:

```
 // Thread 1  init the value:   
 Foo f = new Foo();     
 f.x = 5;     
 values.add(f); // Publication via thread-safe collection like Vector or Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(...)) or ConcurrentHashMap?. 

// Thread 2
if (values.size()>0){        
   System.out.println(values.get(0).x); // always 5 ?
}
```

As I understood Mathias, it can print out 0 on some JVM according to JLS. As I understood axtavt it will always print 5.

What is your opinion?

--
Regards,
Dmitriy

Comment: I cannot decide which answer is correct. Would like to hear opinion of other participants.

Comment: The two answers are compatible. axtavt's does not assume anything about when the threads are started, so it adresses the general case. Mathias's adresses what happens if you do know that your object is constructed and its value setted before the thread is started (which, in axtavt's words, could be seen as a special case of *safe publication*, thanks to the visibility barriers enforced by the starting of a thread ). They complement each other (if your threads are started before the values are set, be carreful where you put your `volatile`s).

Answer (score 9):

In this case you need to use *safe publication idioms* when making your object available to other threads, namely (from [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/)):

> - Initializing an object reference from a static initializer;
> - Storing a reference to it into a volatile field or AtomicReference;
> - Storing a reference to it into a final field of a properly constructed object; or
> - Storing a reference to it into a field that is properly guarded by a lock.

If you use safe publication, you don't need to declare fields `volatile`.

However, if you don't use it, **declaring fields `volatile` (theoretically) won't help**, because memory barriers incurred by `volatile` are one-side: volatile write can be reordered with non-volatile actions after it.

So, `volatile` ensures correctness in the following case:

```
class Foo {
    public int x;
}
volatile Foo foo;

// Thread 1
Foo f = new Foo();
f.x = 42;
foo = f; // Safe publication via volatile reference

// Thread 2
if (foo != null)
     System.out.println(foo.x); // Guaranteed to see 42
```

but don't work in this case:

```
class Foo {
    public volatile int x;
}
Foo foo;

// Thread 1
Foo f = new Foo();
// Volatile doesn't prevent reordering of the following actions!!!
f.x = 42;
foo = f;

// Thread 2
if (foo != null)
     System.out.println(foo.x); // NOT guaranteed to see 42, 
                                // since f.x = 42 can happen after foo = f
```

From the theoretical point of view, in the first sample there is a transitive happens-before relationship

```
f.x = 42 happens before foo = f happens before read of foo.x
```

In the second example `f.x = 42` and read of `foo.x` are not linked by happens-before relationship, therefore they can be executed in any order.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get your statment "declaring fields volatile (theoretically) won't help, because memory barriers icurred by volatile are one-side." Could you please explain what does "one-side" mean? Thank you.

Comment: I think it is clear that the poster does none of these things and wants to know if his code is safe. `Safe publication` seems to be derived practices from the Java concurrency model in JLS chapter 17.

Comment: @axatavt: Yep. Thank you. Now I get it. In my question I meant the first case.

Comment: @axatavt: Sorry:) In fact, did not get it initially:) And what happened if we swap too lines in your first example? `foo = new Foo(); foo.x= 42;`

Comment: @Dime: If you swap these lines, you make object available to other threads before initializing its fields, so that obviously they can see uninitialized fields.

Comment: @axtavt: Added an example to my initial question. Could you please comment my example. thanks.

Comment: @Dime: Your code is correct (though perhaps it should be `get(0)`). Publication via thread-safe collection is a safe publication as well, so you don't need `volatile`.

Comment: @axtavt: Yep. It is get(0) :) So you disagree with Mathias and you think I do not need to make variable x in class Foo volatile because of "transitive happens-before relationship order"?

Comment: @Dime: Yes. My point is that 1) with safe publication you don't need `volatile` fields 2) without safe publication `volatile` fields won't help

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to declare you field volatile of its value is set before the `start` method is called on the threads that read the field.

The reason is that in that case the setting is in a happens-before relation (as defined in the Java Language Specification) with the read in the other thread.

The relevant rules from the JLS are:

- Each action in a thread happens-before every action in that thread that comes later in the program's order
- A call to start on a thread happens-before any action in the started thread.

However, if you start the other threads before setting the field, then you must declare the field volatile. The JLS does not allow you to assume that the thread will not cache the value before it reads it for the first time, even if that may be the case on a particular version of the JVM.

Comment: Incorrect. Declaring fields `volatile` in this case makes no sense and won't help, since publication of the object can be reordered with volatile writes of its fields.

Comment: I am assuming that a single thread is responsible for writing the fields and that the object is published subsequently by the same thread. I think this is clear from the question.

Comment: @axtavt. Why? According your first example if **all** fields are volatile, the second thread will always see the correct values. Isn't it?

Comment: @Mathias Schwarz. Yes, this is exactly what I meant.

Comment: @Dime: Because non-volatile write (unsafe publication of the object) can be reordered with the previous volatile writes (initialization of the fields), see my answer.

Comment: @Dime: Yes, if the other threads do not obtain a reference to the object before all the writes are done. If the writing thread sets the reference to the object on the other threads, then there is a happens-before relation and no reordering can take place. I think this is what axtavt is trying to say, but I think it is clear from your question that this is the case in your code.

Comment: @axtavt: The rule about thread starting in the JLS effectively gives us another safe publication idiom: writing to the object before starting another thread to read from it. It's not a very general idiom, though, since we so rarely create threads.

Comment: Note also that you can only rely on this rule if it's the writing thread that creates the reading threads. If both writer and readers are created by some parent thread, then the rule doesn't help.

Comment: @Tom Anderson: Did you mean the rule "transitive happens-before relationship"? In my case threads are independent (even a reader thread can create a writer thread)

Comment: @Dime: The rule i mean is "a call to start on a thread happens-before any action in the started thread", but that's in concert with the single-thread program-order rule. If thread A writes a value, it is only safe for thread B to read that value if A starts B after writing the value - or if A starts Z, and Z starts B, and so on. If you can trace a line of descent from a point in A after the write to B, then this rule guarantees the write is visible - but only if you can.

Comment: @Tom Anderson: OK. Thank you. This point I got. But my question is more general. In my case the threads have already been started before, so now I am trying to understand if the statement "you must declare the field volatile" of Mathias is correct or not. As I think axtavt meant we do not need "volatile" because of "transitive happens-before relationship" rule. Which actually now makes sense to me...

Comment: My statement is simply that without the `volatile` modifier I cannot identify a happens-before relation between the write and the read. If you can then my statement is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fully understand what's going on I have been reading about the Java Memory Model (JMM). A useful introduction to the JMM can be found in Java Conurrency in Practice.

I think the answer to the question is: yes, in the example given making the members of the object volatile is NOT necessary. However, this implementation is rather brittle as this guarantee depends on the exact ORDER in which things are done and on the Thread-Safety of the Container. A builder pattern would be a much better option.

Why is it guaranteed:

1. The thread 1 does all the assignment BEFORE putting the value into the thread safe container.
2. The add method of the thread safe container must use some synchronization construct like volatile read / write, lock or synchronized(). This guarantees two things:

   1. Instructions which are in thread 1. before the synchronization will actually be executed before. That is the JVM is not allowed to reorder instructions for optimization purposes with the synchronization instruction. This is called happens-before guarantee.
   2. All writes which happen before the synchronization in thread 1 will afterwards be visible to all other threads.
3. The objects are NEVER modified after publication.

However, if the container was not thread safe or the Order of things was changed by somebody not aware of the pattern or the objects are changed accidentally after publication then there are no guarantees anymore. So, following the Builder Pattern, as can be generated by google AutoValue or Freebuilder is much safer.

This article on the topic is also quite good:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html